# Devise multiple step form for registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want the user to be able to register in two steps as I have many fields. Ideally first step would be to accept email and password. As user enter it, they can proceed to fill the next step.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></br>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :city %>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_area :address %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :gender %>
  <span class="option">Male</span><%= f.radio_button :gender, "m" %>
  <span class="option">Female</span><%= f.radio_button :gender, "f" %></br>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :mobile_no %></br>
  <%= f.telephone_field :mobile_no %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :website %>
  <%= f.url_field :website %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @validatable %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :skills %>
  <%= f.text_field :skills %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :passion %>
  <%= f.text_field :passion %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I tried the approach where user enters email and password and after that they are redirected to edit page where they can update other fields.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      redirect_to edit_user_path(resource)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :pro, :amateur, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

However, the redirect doesn't seem to work. I also tried `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` as I am using confirmable, still not working.

I can't seem to figure out why this could be also I would like to know if there are any other approach without using any gem?

Comment: I recommended look at this example at once  http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript if you're just interested in user interface. Or if it's important that you're saving all the info as you're going, you can have the form split into partials and override the devise registration controller to render those separate partials.

You will also need to add steps that link with the partials in your user model. I think if you used a gem, this would probably be main part that it will do for you.

this is a great [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?autoplay=true) on how to have a multistep form without any gems. the only difference is that you'll need to override the create method in devise